# Many to many Laravel issue models?

Tags: laravel

There are two models:

```
class Specialization extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = ['name', 'parentid'];

    public function scopeActive($query)
    {
        return $query->where('status', true);
    }

    public function services()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Service::class);
    }
}
```

```
class Service extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function specializations()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Specialization::class);
    }
}
```

Each specialization has many services. I try to get them:

```
 public function services(Specialization $specialization)
    {


        $specializations = $specialization->services()->get();


        return response()->json($specializations);
    }
```

As result I got this error:

> ```
> "message": "PDO: SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ОШИБКА:  столбец services.specialization_id не существует\nLINE 1: select * from \"services\" where \"services\".\"specialization_id...\n                                       ^ (SQL: select * from \"services\" where \"services\".\"specialization_id\" = 1 and \"services\".\"specialization_id\" is not null)"
> ```
>
> }

Why is field specialization_id looking in services table instead third table?

Comment: `return $this->hasMany(Service::class);` Put this part as `return $this->belongsToMany(Service::class);` and then make pivot table where you will store the data. And you will store the data with `sync()` or `attach()` :)

Comment: Yes, I have replaced the hasMany on belongsToMany. It returns me data with pivot details. But I can not get why I use it instead hasMany?

Comment: Because this way you know which data belongs to which one. If you use has many then it means that other table should have (in your case) `service_id` but then it is One To Many relation, and in many to many you want each data to be linked to the other one and that is why we use pivot tables and these relations for manytomany. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have `belongsToMany` on both relationships.

```php
class Specialization extends Model
{
    public function services()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Service::class);
    }
}
```

```php
class Service extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function specializations()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Specialization::class);
    }
}
```

The default pivot table name will be `service_specialization` I think. If you want to change it, pass it as the 2nd parameter.

Comment: Could you explain why belongsToMany if docs says to use hasMany? And belongsToMany it is back relations, is not?

Comment: hasMany is for [One-to-Many (1:N) relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many). Its reverse is belongsTo. For [Many-to-Many relationships (M:N)](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many), you use belongsToMany for both models.